# Django-cms multisite layout explained

Tags: django, django-cms

How does one serves two sites using one django (django-cms) instance? When I install `site` app and add two site instances using django admin, I get to choose for which one I want to add a page. So here's what I don't get it: how does django should know which site to use? Maybe I'm missing some elements in my django multisite deployment scheme, could somebody put me on track?

Answer (score 2):

Basically, it doesn't know which site to use on its own. You associate each model with a site (or sites), and then check for content with a given site within your views. If you haven't already, check the examples in the [sites doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/sites/) (linked version is 1.5).

It's not really set up for full multitenancy out of the box, in case you're just looking to run a handful of unrelated sites off of one Django install. My own experience in that case was that it was easier to set up separate Django apps and databases for each site, and then use Apache virtual hosts to direct traffic.